# Why doesn't Sonar read the format of django-nose coverage results?

Tags: python, django, sonarqube, code-coverage

When I try to send a python project with sonar-scanner, it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown report version: 4.4.2. 
This parser only handles version 1.".
```

Before trying to introduce the cover, the project was run normally, the project is python code and the report is created with `django-nose`.

More information:

- sonar version: 6.7.1
- sonar scanner command:
  `sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=nanas 
      -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.0.1:9001 -Dsonar.login=F00B4Z`
- sonar doesn't run through a proxy

I'm attaching the sonar project configuration file and coverage xml file generated by `django-nose`.

**Exception:**

```
12:53:31.919 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
Error during parsing of the generic coverage report '/home/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/NAN-CI6-JOB1/xmlrunner/coverage.xml'. Look at SonarQube documentation to know the expected XML format.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown report version: 4.4.2. This parser only handles version 1.
    at org.sonar.scanner.genericcoverage.GenericCoverageReportParser.parseRootNode(GenericCoverageReportParser.java:72)
    at org.sonar.scanner.genericcoverage.GenericCoverageReportParser.lambda$parse$0(GenericCoverageReportParser.java:64)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.StaxParser.parse(StaxParser.java:115)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.StaxParser.parse(StaxParser.java:95)
    at org.sonar.scanner.genericcoverage.GenericCoverageReportParser.parse(GenericCoverageReportParser.java:65)
    at org.sonar.scanner.genericcoverage.GenericCoverageReportParser.parse(GenericCoverageReportParser.java:54)
    at org.sonar.scanner.genericcoverage.GenericCoverageSensor.execute(GenericCoverageSensor.java:109)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

**Configuration:**

```
sonar.projectKey=nanas
sonar.projectName=Nanas
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=nucleo, app_administrador, app_cliente, app_gestor_de_citas, app_nana, app_test, django_gae_emailbackend
sonar.exclusions=**/tests/**, **/static/**/template/**, **/migrations/**, **/__pycache__/**, **/__init__.*
sonar.tests=xmlrunner/nosetests.xml
sonar.genericcoverage.reportPaths=xmlrunner/coverage.xml
sonar.python.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.coverage.dtdVerification=false
```

**Coverage.xml header:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<coverage branch-rate="0" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.5905" lines-covered="1142" lines-valid="1934" timestamp="1516639621366" version="4.4.2">
    <!-- Generated by coverage.py: https://coverage.readthedocs.io -->
    <!-- Based on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cobertura/web/master/htdocs/xml/coverage-04.dtd -->
    <sources>
```

I have configured the scanner according to the indications and I have updated the plugin to version 1.9, but now it generates an error with the number of lines. I have searched several sites for the solution and almost everything comes down to adding a blank line, but this doesn't work.

**Running Test:**

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=app_administrador,app_cliente,app_nana,app_test,app_gestor_de_citas,nucleo --cover-erase --cover-xml --with-xunit --xunit-file=xmlrunner/nosetests.xml --cover-xml-file=xmlrunner/coverage.xml --attr=!pendiente --verbosity=1
```

**Running sonar:**

```
sonar-scanner   -Dsonar.projectKey=nana   -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.0.15:9001   -Dsonar.login=*********
```

**sonar-project.properties**

```
sonar.projectKey=nanas
sonar.projectName=nanas
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=nucleo, app_administrador, app_cliente, app_gestor_de_citas, app_nana, app_test, django_gae_emailbackend
sonar.exclusions=**/tests/**, **/static/**/template/**, **/migrations/**, **/__pycache__/**, **/admin.py
sonar.tests=xmlrunner/nosetests.xml
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=xmlrunner/coverage.xml
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 21 is out of range in the file app_administrador/middleware.py (lines: 19)
        at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
```

**Python plugin**

[SonarPython 1.9 (build 1989)installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7aIE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SonarPython has an embedded support for coverage.py report.
To enable it, you can replace your generic coverage configuration:

```
sonar.genericcoverage.reportPaths=xmlrunner/coverage.xml
sonar.python.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.coverage.dtdVerification=false
```

By the specific SonarPython configuration:

```
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=xmlrunner/coverage.xml
```

For more details see [Python Coverage Results Import](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Python+Coverage+Results+Import)

Note: Improvements have been made in SonarPython 1.9 related to coverage.py (up to 4.4.2), if you can not yet download SonarPython 1.9 the release candidate is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/sonarqube/-REdRnFeQXA).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was going on. It seems that the scanner confuses two files of the same name in different django apps because each app was configured as "cover-package" in django settings for django-nose.

Apparently django-nose treats all packet root files as a single module ". /" and if there is a repeated file (example: admin.py) only reads one but when you pass the data to the python scanner, it tries to read another one and if they both have different lines it throws the conflict, and I imagine that if they happen to have the same lines, the representation in sonar covered code vs. lines, would also be wrong.

**Coverage file generated by django-nose before change:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<coverage branch-rate="0" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.5905" lines-covered="1142" lines-valid="1934" timestamp="1516895775536" version="4.4.2">
    <!-- Generated by coverage.py: https://coverage.readthedocs.io -->
    <!-- Based on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cobertura/web/master/htdocs/xml/coverage-04.dtd -->
    <sources>
        <source>/home/jvallina/PycharmProjects/nana_project/app_administrador</source>
        <source>/home/jvallina/PycharmProjects/nana_project/app_cliente</source>
        <source>/home/jvallina/PycharmProjects/nana_project/app_gestor_de_citas</source>
        <source>/home/jvallina/PycharmProjects/nana_project/app_nana</source>
        <source>/home/jvallina/PycharmProjects/nana_project/app_test</source>
        <source>/home/jvallina/PycharmProjects/nana_project/nucleo</source>
    </sources>
    <packages>
        <package branch-rate="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.5668" name=".">
            <classes>
                <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="__init__.py" line-rate="1" name="__init__.py">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines/>
                </class>
                <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="admin.py" line-rate="0" name="admin.py">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line hits="0" number="1"/>
                        ...
                        <line hits="0" number="238"/>
                    </lines>
                </class>
```

Then we have to replace it (django settings):

```
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=app_administrador,app_cliente,app_nana,app_test,app_gestor_de_citas,nucleo',
    '--cover-erase',
    '--cover-xml',
    '--with-xunit',
    '--xunit-file=xmlrunner/nosetests.xml',
    '--cover-xml-file=xmlrunner/coverage.xml'
]
```

with that:

```
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=.',
    '--cover-erase',
    '--cover-xml',
    '--with-xunit',
    '--xunit-file=xmlrunner/nosetests.xml',
    '--cover-xml-file=xmlrunner/coverage.xml'
]
```

**Coverage file after the change:**
We can see that each file repeated in the modules is already differentiated by its source app.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <coverage branch-rate="0" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.6718" lines-covered="3069" lines-valid="4568" timestamp="1516896635767" version="4.4.2">
        <!-- Generated by coverage.py: https://coverage.readthedocs.io -->
        <!-- Based on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cobertura/web/master/htdocs/xml/coverage-04.dtd -->
        <sources>
            <source>/home/jvallina/PycharmProjects/nana_project</source>
        </sources>
        <packages>
            <package branch-rate="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0" name=".">
                <classes>
                    <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="manage.py" line-rate="0" name="manage.py">
                        <methods/>
                        <lines>
                            <line hits="0" number="2"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="3"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="5"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="6"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="7"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="8"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="9"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="13"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="14"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="15"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="16"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="21"/>
                            <line hits="0" number="22"/>
                        </lines>
                    </class>
                </classes>
            </package>
            <package branch-rate="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.4884" name="app_administrador">
    <classes>
                    <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="app_administrador/__init__.py" line-rate="1" name="__init__.py">
                        <methods/>
                        <lines/>
                    </class>
                    <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="app_administrador/admin.py" line-rate="1" name="admin.py">
                        <methods/>
                        <lines/>
                    </class>
    ...
    </package>
<package branch-rate="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.7931" name="app_cliente">
            <classes>
                <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="app_cliente/__init__.py" line-rate="1" name="__init__.py">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines/>
                </class>
                <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="app_cliente/admin.py" line-rate="1" name="admin.py">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines/>
                </class>
...
</package>
```

Comment: Your investigation highlights a limitation in SonarPython 1.9 RC. It resolves the `filename` attribute of the `coverage.xml` file with the first occurrence of `<source>` element. Instead, it should take into account all the `<source>` elements. Here is the ticket [SONARPY-257](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-257). Thanks for your feedback.